# How to latch a signal rise and low on the next signal rise

Tags: latch, edge

My input signal is a pulsing 35Hz with a top at 5 volts. The pulses itself are short.
The first pulse (5v) should trigger a latch at 5v high. And the next pulse should reset the latch to low.

Added a illustration below to make it more clear. Who can point me in the right direction?

[image]

Comment: How about a rising edge triggered flip-flop?

Comment: Specifically a "toggle" FF. You can make one by tying the D input of a DFF to the not-Q output, or by tying the J and K inputs of a JKFF high. Note that DFFs are usually positive edge triggered, while JKFFs are often negative edge triggered.

Comment: Hmm. But it looks like the output needs to anticipate the rising edge of the input. It leads. What's needed here is the *acausal*-DFF with adjustable prescience. I'd like one, myself.

Comment: @jonk For one design quite early in my career, we decided that the only solution to our de-jittering problem was a pulse-anticipator circuit.

Comment: @Neil_UK Well, your solution would be a key component in my proposed acausal-DFF. Please feel free to disclose your solution to us. ;)

Comment: Checked out the "toggle" FF, that seems to be the right direction. Does this also work with a changing frequency between 20 and 200 Hz. An important part for the DFF to work, seems to be the gate time.

Comment: Since it works in MHz range, no problem.

Comment: As long as the pulse transitions are fast enough for the flip flop clock inout. Digital circuits don't like slow transitions, and some preconditioning can be done to make them fast enough.

Comment: You can use a rising edge triggered flip-flop to toggle at each pulse.

Comment: @Justme  You suggested the edge triggered FF 1st in comments and I see the same suggestion as an answer has been converted to a comment.  Very short answers (even correct ones) run the risk of being comment -converted. Adding a basic toggling FF diagram may well have prevented this.

Comment: ... Lots of [instant diagrams](https://www.google.com/search?q=toggle+flip+flop&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiStafknKTrAhVOJbcAHXBLCbYQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=toggle+flip+flop&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAIEB5Q0pkBWNKZAWCMnAFoAHAAeACAAd0BiAHdAZIBAzItMZgBAKABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1nwAEB&sclient=img&ei=iII7X5LRKM7K3LUP8JalsAs&bih=1269&biw=2457&rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ834NZ839) available :-).